# How to Set color in CCMenuItem in cocos2d Iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to set the Background color of CCMenuItem in Cocos2d Iphone ?

what should we do  for that ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new CCSprite with a black texture (programmatically)

and than add that to the ccmenuitem.